# I have two different values for an attribute. I want to count the number of times both values appear and then divide by the total. SQL

Tags: sql

I have some data on a football match here. Where I'm trying to message the dribble success of a player. There are two outcomes that can be seen in the outcome field, either a dribble is completed or not. I want to know what SQL Query I can write to get the total number of completed dribbles per player and then divide by the total number of dribbles attempted (completed and incompleted) then multiply by 100% so I can have a dribble success rate for each player. Basically, (complete/incomplete+complete)*100. I've been struggling with this

[image]

This is my awful Query so far which can doesn't allow me to show the two players who had 0 completed dribbles

```
SELECT PLAYER, COUNT, TOTAL, (COUNT/TOTAL * 100) AS Completed
FROM
(
    SELECT PLAYER,OUTCOME, CAST (COUNT AS FLOAT) AS COUNT, TOTAL(COUNT) as TOTAL
    FROM
    (
        SELECT PLAYER, OUTCOME,COUNT(*) as Count 
        FROM DRIBBLES
        GROUP BY PLAYER,OUTCOME
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, PLAYER
    )
    GROUP BY PLAYER
)
WHERE OUTCOME = 'Complete'
GROUP BY PLAYER
ORDER BY Completed DESC;
```

Comment: Skip the outer GROUP BY.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @VinitPatel . . . Nothing in your table says "dribble", so I don't know what you are looking for nor what results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you

```
SELECT Player, 
CASE 
    WHEN TotalDribbles <> 0 
    THEN (SuccessfulDribbles * 100.0 / TotalDribbles)  
    ELSE 0 END as SuccessPercentage
FROM ( SELECT 
    Player,
    sum(case when OUTCOME = 'Complete' then 1 else 0 end) as SuccessfulDribbles,
    count(*) as TotalDribbles
    FROM DRIBBLES
    GROUP BY Player
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select player,
       avg(case when outcome = 'Complete' then 100.0 else 0 end) as complete_percentage
from dribbles
group by player;
```